Why is my bevel modifier tearing my geometry at the corner?
I have been battling a problem which I need some help figuring out. I have been using Blender to fold up box dielines, and I keep running into the same problem. Basically when I add a bevel modifier, it is breaking at the corner of the fold. I've tried a few things including adding more geometry and increasing the distance from another fold and nothing seems to help.
Any tips or tricks would be hugely appreciated.




After some experimentation, it seems that the bevel doesn't like an angled endpoint. I added some extra geometry and squared off the end and it works much better now – not perfect but much better.
Note: blue lines show bevel weight set to "1", all other lines set to "0".



If I understand it correctly, the main goal here is to deform an object with an armature. At the moment you are trying to shape some object to have a realistic form after the deformation by adding bevel after the armature. Consider a more traditional approach of having the topology right for simulating the correct deformation in the first place so you don't need any bevel modifiers at the end. That will require modelling correct topology that can be deformed in the desired way and you will need to paint/create weights correctly. That's a more usual workflow for things like this.

Thanks for your response. I tried reordering the modifiers to have the armature last, but it didn't help. I think the problem I was experiencing was a quirk of the bevel modifier, where it seems to need a square end to work nicely.

You misunderstood what I was trying to communicate completely. I am not suggesting to just switch modifier order. I am suggesting to model the topology required for a more complex deformation. The bends "overlap" in that corner so more complex transition from one to another would happen if something was bent this way, possibly stretching the material or reducing the bend near the corner.
